# Unsatisfied dependency when running a Junit Test in Spring app

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, integration-testing

I have this configuration class in a maven project:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Configuration
public class SmsConfig {

    @Value("${sms.domainId}")
    private String domainId;

    @Value("${sms.gateway.url}")
    private String gatewayUrl;

    @Value("${sms.cmd}")
    private String cmd;

    @Value("${sms.login}")
    private String login;

    @Value("${sms.passwd}")
    private String passwd;

}
```

I have this service class in a Spring project:

```
Service("smsService")
public class AltiriaSMSRestServiceImpl implements SmsService {

    private final SmsConfig smsConfig;

    public AltiriaSMSRestServiceImpl(SmsConfig smsConfig) {
        this.smsConfig = smsConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean sendSMS(String msg, String to) throws Exception {
    ...
    }
...
}
```

and this Test:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SmsConfig.class })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class AltiriaSMSRestServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("smsService")
    private AltiriaSMSRestServiceImpl smsService;

    @Test
    public void testSendSMS() throws Exception {
        smsService.sendSMS("this is a test", "+34776498");
    }

}
```

but when I run the test I have this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.bonanza.service.AltiriaSMSRestServiceImplTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'smsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.bonanza.service.AltiriaSMSRestServiceImpl' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="smsService")}

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)
```

Comment: Specify the altiriasmsrestserviceimpl class in ur context configuration, it should work then.

Comment: What is `SmsConfig`, a `@Configuration`?  If so, this is not the way to initialize the service, you want to declare a `@Bean` in the config.

Comment: '@Bean' is not aplicable to Type

Comment: @IndraneelBende, please convert to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confusing Spring configuration and configuration properties.

```
@Service("smsService")
public class AltiriaSMSRestServiceImpl implements SmsService {

    private final SmsConfigData smsConfig;

    public AltiriaSMSRestServiceImpl(SmsConfigData smsConfig) {
        this.smsConfig = smsConfig;
    }
    ...
}

// the configuration data, mapped to the application.properties/yml file
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="sms")
@Data
public class SmsConfigData {

    @Value("${domainId}")
    private String domainId;
    ...
}

// this is a spring configuration class, ie the definition of spring beans
// I don't think you even need this, since the 
// SmsConfigData gets constructor-injected automatically
// this is the class that gets included in the test config class list

@Configuration
public class SmsServiceConfiguration {
@Bean
SmsService smsService(SmsConfigData config) {
    return new AltiriaSMSRestServiceImpl(config);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `AltiriaSMSRestServiceImpl` class in your context configuration. Specify the `AltiriaSMSRestServiceImpl` class in ur context configuration, it should work then.